# Mostrar Imagenes Con PHP

Tags: php

*Hola, buenas tardes.... Podrian ayudarme, es que necesito mostrar unas imagenes, pero osea, en la bd, tengo una tabla lacual contiene 1400 datos, y tengo una pagina web con la que al seleccionar un solo dato, me trae todas las caracteristicas de ese dato seleccionado, pero ahora solo me falta la imagen, y es que osea tengo que crearotra tabla, pero nose si alamacenar la imagen en la bd, o guardar solo el nombre de la imagen, ademas de eso, en la primera tabla mensionada antes, hay cinco campos en los cuales hay palabras como "atencion", "corrosivo", entons necesito que segun el campo seleccionado, si esta tiene por ejemplo "atencion" que me traiga a pantalla solo la imagen que represente "atencion"*

```html
---------Archivo Conexion---------------
<?php

//Conexion A La Base De Datos
    $host="localhost";
    $usuario="root";
    $contraseña="";
    $base="etiquetame";

    $conexion = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $contraseña, $base);
    
    if ($conexion -> connect_errno){
        die ("Fallo La Conexion:(".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_errno().")".$conexion-> mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>

---------Archivo Index---------------
<?php
    include ("control/conexion.php");
    //Consulta A La Base De Datos
    $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM basede");
    //Filtro
    $idproduc = '';
    $idproduc = $_POST['producto'];

    if($idproduc!=""){
        $where ="where id=".$idproduc;
    }else{
        $where="";
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ETIQUETAME</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <!--Carga De Archivos Css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="Cuerpouno">
                
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    
                <select name="producto" id="producto">
                    <option>Seleccione Una Opción</option>
                    <?php
                        while($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
                            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['Nombre']."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                
                </select>
                
                <input id="consultar" type="submit" value="Consultar">

            </form>
            
            <table class="tabla">
                <tr>
                    
                    <th class="uno"><b>CAS: </b></th>
                    <th class="dos"><b>Concentración: </b></th>
                    <th class="tres"><b>Formula: </b></th>
                    <th class="cuatro"><b>Densidad: </b></th>
                    <th class="cinco"></th>
                    <th class="once"></th>
                    <th class="doce"></th>
                    <th class="trece"><em>Advertencia De Peligros</em></th>
                    <th class="catorce"></th>
                    <th class="quince"><em>Consejos De Prudencia</em></th>
                    <th class="dieseis"></th>
                    <th class="diesiete"></th>
                    <th class="diesnueve"></th>
                    <th class="veintiuno"><b>M:</b></th>
                    <th class="veinticuatro"><img class="tres" src="img/Univ.png"></th>
                    <th class="veintisiete"></th>
                    <th class="veintiocho"><img class="cuatro" src="img/Univ.png"></th>
                    <th class="treinta"></th>
                    <th class="treintauno"></th>
                    <th class="treintacuatro"></th>
                    <th class="treintacinco"></th>
                    <th class="treintaseis"></th>
                    <th class="treintasiete"></th>
                    <th class="treintaocho"></th>
                    <th class="treintanueve"></th>
                </tr>
                
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `CAS`, `Nombre`, `ColorDeEtiqueta`, `Etiqueta 1`, `Etiqueta 2`, `Etiqueta 3`, `Etiqueta 4`, `Etiqueta 5`, `Frase H1`, `Frase H2`, `Frase H3`, `Frase H4`, `Frase H5`, `Frase H6`, `Frase H7`, `Frase H8`, `Frase H9`, `Frase H10`, `Frase H11`, `Frase H12`, `Frase P1`, `Frase P2`, `Frase P3`, `Frase P4`, `Frase P5`, `Frase P6`, `Frase P7`, `Frase P8`, `Frase P9`, `Frase P10`, `Frase P11`, `Frase P12`, `Frase P13`, `Frase P14`, `Frase P15`, `Frase P16`, `Frase P17`, `Frase P18`, `Frase P19`, `Frase P20`, `Frase P21`, `Frase P22`, `Frase P23`, `Frase P24`, `Frase P25`, `Frase P26`, `Frase P27`, `Frase P28`, `Frase P29`, `Frase P30`, `UN`, `Almacenamiento`, `Palabra`, `Etiquetas 1`, `Etiquetas 2`, `Etiquetas 3`, `Sinonimos`, `Formula`, `PM`, `Densidad`, `Pureza`, `Concentracion` FROM `basede` WHERE id='".$idproduc."'";
                    $sqlquery = $conexion->query($sql);
                    while ($Muestra = $sqlquery->fetch_array()){
                ?>
                
                <tr><td class="diez"><b><?php echo $Muestra['Nombre']?></b></td></tr><tr><td class="seis"><?php echo $Muestra['CAS'];?></td><td class="siete"><?php echo $Muestra['Concentracion'];?></td><td class="ocho"><?php echo $Muestra['Formula'];?></td><td class="nueve"><?php echo $Muestra['Densidad'];?></td><td class="veinte"><?php echo $Muestra['PM']?></td><td class="veintitres"><b>Clase</b><br><?php echo $Muestra['Almacenamiento']?></td></tr>
                
                <tr><td class="diesocho"><b><?php echo $Muestra['Nombre']?></b></td><td class="veinticinco"><?php echo $Muestra['Formula']?></td><td class="veintiseis"><?php echo $Muestra['PM']?></td><td class="veintinueve"></td><td class="treintados"><b>Clase: <?php echo $Muestra['Almacenamiento']?></b></td><td class="treintatres"></td>
                </tr>
                        
                <?php
                    }
                
                ?>
                
            </table>
    
                <input type="submit" name="btncas" value="Buscar Por CAS" id="btncas">
                <input type="submit" name="menuP" value="Menú Principal" id="menuP">
                <input type="submit" name="buscarfds" value="Buscar FDS" id="buscarfds">
                <input type="submit" name="aggfds" value="Agregar FDS" id="aggfds">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para tu caso sólo deberías guardar la ruta donde se almacena la imagen física; creo que hay tipos de datos (en versiones actuales de los gestores de bases) que soportan guardar imágenes, pero ignoro como trabajan

Comment: No creo que necesites guardar eso en la db, tal vez podrías hacer directamente en php una validación: if (texto=="corrosivo") {echo "<img src='ruta'>"}

Comment: Pero en caso que por ejemplo tenga una categoría **corrosivo**, y ésta a su vez posea muchas imágenes, tendría que realizar un `echo <img />` por cada una

Comment: Si Emiliano, lo mismo tenia pensado hacerlo asi, solo que la persona a la cual le estoy haciendo el programa, me dijo que lo hiciera guardando el nombre de la imagten en la bd, y luego concatenara la extencion de la imagen

Answer (score 0):

En la base de datos guardas la ruta de la imagen, y luego al extraer el dato, con php imprimes algo así:

```
echo '<img src="'.$ruta.'">';
```